# TypeORM, condition for two database columns at the same row

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm currently working on project with NestJS and I just wanna ask if there is a way to set condition for two database columns at the same row in typeORM in **where** option

ex: I have two columns in database **postpondedDate** and **createdAt**... at first I'll check if **postpondedDate** is not null, if it's not I'll use **MoreThan(new Date())**, if it's null I'll go to check the value of **createdAt** with the same option **MoreThan(new Date())**

here is an example code:

```
async handleCron(){
   const activeStudents = await this.invoiceService.find({
      select: ['id', 'student', 'postpondedDate', 'createdAt'],
      relations: ['student'],
      where: {
         // if postponded date !== null I'll use
         // postpondedDate: MoreThan(new Date()),

         // if postponded date === null dont check this column and go to createdAt
         // createdAt: MoreThan(new Date()),
      },
   });
}
```

> **Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where: [
    {postponded: MoreThan(new Date())},
    {postponded:null, createdAt: MoreThan(new Date())},
  }]
```

That's simply an OR: postponded is higher OR (postponded is null AND created is higher)